# Can TCP and TLS use the same port number at the same time?

Tags: tcp, port, tls1.2

Can the server handle both TCP and TLS connections through only one port number?

Comment: TLS is a protocol (usually) on top of TCP so this question does not make much sense. If you want to know if a specific protocol on top of TCP (like for example HTTP, FTP...) can be run on the same port number then you need to ask a question which specifically describes this other protocol. It will work for some (like HTTP) but will not work for others (like FTP). Usually it can be made working for protocols where the client sends the first data so that the decision can be based on the first data from the client (either TLS ClientHello or something else non-TLS).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is usually the case that every TLS connection *is* a TCP connection, if this wasn't the case, we couldn't use TLS the way we typically do at all. TLS requires a reliable byte-stream protocol to layer on top off. This is most commonly TCP.